# Directory for saving project-independent settings for a Unity tool?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a tool/plugin for Unity and I can't find info on where third party tools/plugins of Unity can save their project-independent settings. I want to achieve that if a user imports my plugin into a new project the plugin would load it's settings if there are any (generated when used in previous projects) from some default directory - preferably directory managed by Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for EditorPrefs:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorPrefs.html

This allows you to store data in a project unrelated location. Storing and retrieving data in the editor preferences works like a Dictionary container in C# (Key / Value pairs). Let's say we want to save the user's name:

`EditorPrefs.SetString("UserName", "Jon");`

And retreiving that value would look like this:

`var name = EditorPrefs.GetString("UserName");`

Comment: @MaciejLach Just updated my response with some more information.  Anything else that may have been left unsaid / assumed?